# What is a multi-rate non preemptive OS?

Tags: operating-system, embedded, dispatcher, rtos, preemption

I have this question related to embedded systems, this expression which i found in a source file of a dispatcher:

```
What is a multi-rate non preemptive OS / Dispatcher ?
```

I know a little about dispatcher , non-preemptive systems RTOS based on my research etc ... but i didn't found the expression combined.

What i can understand is that the Dispatcher  is the entity responsible for adding a process/thread to the run queue. Non preemptive means that a task when it began to run it cannot be stopped by another task until it finishes and multi-rate means that the dispatcher will keep running tasks like a while(1) loop.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Note: the multi-rate tag doesn't exist yet on SO so it's not mentionned :p

Answer (score 2):

This article provides a great explanation and example of a multi-rate non-preemptive scheduler: [Multi-Rate Main Loop Tasking](http://betterembsw.blogspot.com/2015/12/multi-rate-main-loop-tasking.html)

To summarize, imagine a scheduler or main loop that calls a series of functions that each represent a different task.  Non-preemptive means that a task cannot preempt another task but that each task yields (returns) back to the scheduler (main loop) so that the scheduler can run another task.  Multi-rate means that the scheduler can call each task function at a different periodic rate.  In other words, not every task function is called every time through the main loop and some task functions are called more often than others.